# Remove the last '|' and read all the data as a dataset

Tags: c#

```
69|M2200|D9612|0000000|20070101|
87|M20888|D5710|0032600|20071101|
```

Now I want to remove the last '|'

And read all the data as a dataset.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are supposed to be about solving problems you have with your code. SO is not a place where you go to have other's write the code for you. In this question you have only the data, no indication of how your have tried to parse it, what the problems were with you attempt and so on... In order to get help here, you need to try to solve the issue yourself, and then if you fail, describe what you have tried and what kind of errors you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you have:

```
string str = "69|M2200|D9612|0000000|20070101| 87|M20888|D5710|0032600|20071101|";
string strWithout = hh.Remove(hh.LastIndexOf('|'));
```

The method `"LastIndexOF('|')"` returns the last index of char '|' in your `string` and so it is possible to remove a character from necessary index using method `string.Remove(index);`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
string[] dataset= "69|M2200|D9612|0000000|20070101|".Split( new char[]{'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```